# Set react keys unique by using shortid.generate () in this way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
import shortid from "shortid";

export const NavArray = [
  {
    to: "/Women",
    text: "1",
    id: shortid.generate()
  },
  {
    to: "/Women",
    text: "2",
    id: shortid.generate()
  },
  {
    to: "/Women",
    text: "3",
    id: shortid.generate()
  },
  {
    to: "/Women",
    text: "4",
    id: shortid.generate()
  }
];
```

Can I use the above method to render dynamic data like  :

```
NavArray.map(val => <div key={val.id}>{val.text}</div> )
```

Or should I use like below: `NavArray without id key`

```
NavArray.map(val => <div key={shortid.generate()}>{val.text}</div> )
```

Any suggestions on this, really helpful.

Comment: Answered your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794896/2245264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

I guess your `generate` method gives you a random value of some sort. Using the method given in your first solution, this generated ID will stay the same for every elements, which is what React expects.

However, the second method will generate a different ID every time it is called and may have a performance cost. A component's `key`should always remain the same even when it is re-rendered, using this solution, it not be the case and slow down your application.

Answer (score 2):

When rendering long lists on react we need to tell react with an key So that react will compare new created virtual dom with the previous dom. If the key changes every time then React can't compare newly created Virtual dom with previous Dom. 
So, As a thumb rule you should not change the key's of child when rerender is called.