# I am getting a unique key prop warning when i have a unique key

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactive-programming

I am new to React but I know main concept of unique key. However, I am getting a warning.

Below I have an item component:

```
class Item extends Component {
    state = {}

    render() { 
        return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.props.item.todo}
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

And below is my items component and where i have unique keys:

```
render() { 
    const { items } = this.props;
    return ( 
        items.map(item=>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Item key={item.todo} item={item} />
            </React.Fragment>
        )    
    );
}
```

With all of this I am getting warning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said you need to set the `key` on the top element, in your case being `Fragment`. But I would change the key value. I don't know what kind of data you have in your `item.todo` but just setting the key to the value of `item.todo` could be problematic. I will explain.

**A key should be unique only among its siblings**

The react.org document on lists and keys sums this up perfectly, so I won't explain in another way. It says this below.

> Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However, they don’t need to be globally unique. We can use the same keys when we produce two different arrays:

(Note: it does not need to be meaningful data).

**A key should be stable**

This means that between renders the key should not change, so don't use `Math.random()` which *some* people think would be good to use.

**Why is the above important?**

In your data, if two `items.todo` are the same value then it would break the above. Your key would not be unique. Which could cause performance issues from unnecessary re-renders.

I would recommend using a key with the value of the `items.todo` and the `index` of the map. This way if you do have the same value for `items.todo` adding an index would make the key unique. With this in mind I would write your snippet.

```
render() { 
  const { items } = this.props;

  return ( 
    items.map((item, index) => (
      <React.Fragment key={item.todo + index}>
        <Item item={item} />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))
  );
}
```

Here is link to the react.org documentation on [list and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and is a link to the react.org documentation regarding [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). Both provide examples and useful information. They are a good read and I would highly recommend.

Also something I noticed is that you're using `React.Fragment` but then you declare your class with just `Component`. Your could do what I'm assuming you've done for `Component` and destructure the `Fragement`. Something like below:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
```

So you're snippet is a bit more clean, like below:

```
items.map((item, index) => (
  <Fragment key={item.todo + index}>
    <Item item={item} />
  <Fragment>
))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep the `key` props on the top element as @Tholle suggested in the answer. But here, what I want to suggest is not to use the `<React.Fragment>`:

```
items.map(item=>
   <Item key={item.todo} item={item} />
)
```

The `Fragment` is used whenever you don't want to wrap the elements with a wrapper like `<div />`, `<p />`, etc. Since you have the `<Item />` component, using `Fragment` is unnecessary.

Here's the example in case you may use the `Fragment`:

```
items.map(item=>
   <React.Fragment key={item.todo}>
     <Item item={item} />
     <p>Another Component...</p>
   </React.Fragment>
)
```

But sorry if you use alias of `Fragment`: the `<></>` doesn't support `key` props. It should be explicitly set with no props at all. You'll need to wrap them by an element if you need to use `key`:

```
items.map(item=>
   <div key={item.todo}>
     <Item item={item} />
     <p>Another Component...</p>
   </div>
)
```

This will be invalid:

```
items.map(item=>
   <key={item.todo}>
     <Item item={item} />
     <p>Another Component...</p>
   </>
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the `key` prop on the top element, i.e. `React.Fragment` instead of `Item`.

```
items.map(item=>
  <React.Fragment key={item.todo}>
    <Item item={item} />
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

give key to React.Fragment

```
render() { 
  const { items } = this.props;

  return ( 
    items.map(item =>
      <React.Fragment key={item.todo}>
        <Item item={item} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) npm package. It is described as 'Amazingly short non-sequential url-friendly unique id generator.'

Using the array index as a key is an anti-pattern. Read more on [this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).
ESLINT also prevents this -> [Prevent usage of Array index in keys (react/no-array-index-key)](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md)

Here is how I used it.

```
npm install shortid


import shortid from 'shortid'

// using https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid to prevent duplicate fragment keys
names.map(name => {
    return (
        <Fragment key={`fragment-${id}-${shortid.generate()}`}>
            Hello, {name}!
        </Fragment>
    )
});
```

Comment: By using the `generate` function inside a `map` you'll have a different key for the same element on every re-render, which is not what React expects. Check the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys